# Push Notification not work correctly in custom app [Rocket.chat]

Tags: push-notification, rocket.chat

I followed the instructions in the Rocket.chat documentation:

- Removed the check mark from the gateway
- added GCM keys from firebase
- rebooted the server

Pushs seem to come, but the listener "pushnotificationreceived" is triggered only if I open the application immediately after the push should come or I am in the application during the push, if I have minimized the application and send myself a message, then there is no push.

If I throw the push myself through the firebase API, then the push works out as needed.
There is a suspicion that this is due to the fact that Rocket.chat sends push data in the data key, not notification (https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/blob/develop/app/push/server/gcm.js).

I also have an error in the Rocket logs.Chat:
"For devices running Android 8.0 or later, you need to specify the android_channel_id identifier. See https://github.com/raix/push/issues/341 for more information", but even with this error, push writes that it was sent successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Please, checkout this post:

https://forums.rocket.chat/t/apple-push-notification-service-update-from-legacy-binary-protocol/12425/4

Also, consider asking dev questions at:
https://open.rocket.chat/channel/dev